# Spring Testing with HibernateCallback not working

Tags: java, spring

I try to test the **WriteTxnFinishProcessorTest** and it run without any exception.
The hibernate log show it rollback correctly but the db field '**LastUpdateTime**' still update new value. 
Why? 
Does HibernateCallback not under the hibernate transaction?

the log show as follow:

```
[main         ] 20120104 15:44:54.284 INFO  HibernateTransactionManager - Using DataSource [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 5000, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 2sa1nt8k1aivnzwna070g|1a7b0bf, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> true, description -> null, driverClass -> com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 2sa1nt8k1aivnzwna070g|1a7b0bf, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 120, initialPoolSize -> 2, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:sybase:Tds:10.10.10.203:6332/NIAIMM, lastAcquisitionFailureDefaultUser -> null, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 180, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 120, maxPoolSize -> 50, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 2, numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 60, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
[main         ] 20120104 15:44:54.557 DEBUG AbstractPlatformTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [testProcessIn]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
[main         ] 20120104 15:44:54.614 DEBUG HibernateTransactionManager - Opened new Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@6af2fb] for Hibernate transaction
[main         ] 20120104 15:44:54.619 DEBUG HibernateTransactionManager - Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@6af2fb]
[main         ] 20120104 15:44:54.652 DEBUG HibernateTransactionManager - Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@11f5ff9]
[main         ] 20120104 15:44:54.668 DEBUG LoggingAspect        - DAO:GenericDAOImpl.executeHQLUpdate
[main         ] 20120104 15:44:54.680 DEBUG LoggingAspect        - args:[update DailyImmigrationsTemp set ImmigRcode='0000', LastUpdateTime=?, TxnMark=0 where EdCardNo=? and Port=? and ImmigrateDate=? and ImmigrateSeq=?, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1267610]
[main         ] 20120104 15:44:55.372 DEBUG SQLStatementLogger   - update DailyImmigrationsTemp set ImmigRcode='0000', LastUpdateTime=?, TxnMark=0 where EdCardNo=? and Port=? and ImmigrateDate=? and ImmigrateSeq=?
[main         ] 20120104 15:44:55.421 WARN  LoggingAspect        - execution  time:740 ms, return:1
[main         ] 20120104 15:44:55.422 DEBUG AbstractPlatformTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
[main         ] 20120104 15:44:55.422 DEBUG HibernateTransactionManager - Rolling back Hibernate transaction on Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@6af2fb]
[main         ] 20120104 15:44:55.455 DEBUG HibernateTransactionManager - Closing Hibernate Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@6af2fb] after transaction
```

===WriteTxnFinishProcessorTest.java===

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:applicationContextTest.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="txManager",defaultRollback=true)
@Transactional
public class WriteTxnFinishProcessorTest {
    @Autowired 
    private GenericDAO dailyImmigrationsTempDAO;

    @Test
    public void testProcessIn() {
        String  hql="update DailyImmigrationsTemp set LastUpdateTime=? where EdCardNo=? and Port=? and ImmigrateDate=? and ImmigrateSeq=?";
        Object[] params=new Object[]{new Date(),"5550137001",12,"20111214",1};
        int cnt = dailyImmigrationsTempDAO.executeHQLUpdate(hql, params);
        System.out.println("cnt:"+cnt);
    }
}
```

===DailyImmigrationsTempDAO.java===

```
   :
   :
public int executeHQLUpdate(final String hql, final Object[] params ){
    int ret = (Integer)getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback<Object>() {
        public Object doInHibernate(Session sess) throws HibernateException {
            Query query = sess.createQuery(hql);
            for (int i=0;i<params.length;i++){
              query.setParameter(i, params[i]);  
            }
            return query.executeUpdate();
        }
    });
    return ret;
}
```

===applicationContextTest.xml===

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        :
        : 
    </bean>
    <bean id="abstractDAO" abstract="true">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.pojo</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dailyImmigrationsTempDAO" class="com.dao.GenericDAOImpl" parent="abstractDAO">
        <constructor-arg value="com.pojo.DailyImmigrationsTemp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Does class DailyImmigrationsTempDAO or method executeHQLUpdate have Transactiontal annotation?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be changing the defaults for Spring transactional tests, so the @TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="txManager",defaultRollback=true) line doesn't seem to be doing anything.  However, you're referencing a bean called txManager, which is not declared in your bean configuration file.  From the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations):

> @TransactionConfiguration
>
> Defines class-level metadata for configuring transactional tests.
>   Specifically, the bean name of the PlatformTransactionManager that is
>   to be used to drive transactions can be explicitly configured if the
>   bean name of the desired PlatformTransactionManager is not
>   "transactionManager". In addition, you can change the defaultRollback
>   flag to false. Typically, @TransactionConfiguration is used in
>   conjunction with @ContextConfiguration.

The spring test runner may be getting confused about your transaction manager; the implicit one that is created by the configuration shown is named 'transactionManager'.  Try removing that line altogether.  Another thing to try would be to annotate your executeHQLUpdate() method explicitly with @Transactional.